# Flutter Inkwell navigator context not working in Card

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I try to make touchable Card with Inkwell but my navigator context not working.
This is my Card widget code, I didn't understand why it's not working. Thanks for help.

```
  Widget buildResultCard(data) {
  return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      elevation: 5,
      child: InkWell(
       //this context have issue 
        onTap: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('yol');},
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),


                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 10),
                      child: Text(data['isim'],
                        style:  GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontSize: 24 , textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(thickness: 3,),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 10),
                      child: Text(data['tarih'],
                        style:  GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontSize: 24 , textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                   
                  ],
                )
            )
        ),
      )
  );
}
```

And this is my Body Code that I use.

```
body: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          color: myColor,

          child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,


                children: <Widget>[

                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  GridView.count(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.8,

                      primary: false,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                        return buildResultCard(element);
                      }).toList()),

                  SizedBox(height: 30,),


                ]),

        )
```

'yol' : (context) => Wrapper()  this is route on my main.dart file

Comment: when ı changed "data" to "context" its working but this time return buildResultCard(element);    element give issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `BuildContext` to your function parameters

`Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context, data) {`

or wrap your Card in a `Builder` widget.

Comment: Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context, data)  when I change like this , element give issue again

Comment: @AlperBorabay Just to make sure, you've changed `buildResultCard(element)` to `buildResultCard(context, element)` in your Body Code? Could you maybe add the errors you're getting to your question